# Invertible Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that the transpose operation defined on the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{n×n}$ is an invertible transformation and determine the matrix representation of this transform.

Comment: kindly include your attempt.

Comment: I have done the first part of this question . 
let the element of an nXn matrix be aij then we can apple the transform as , 
A(aij) = aji ; now if we take A(aji) we get aij .  Thus this is an inverse of itself.

Comment: "Apple" the transform ? No ad on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You proved correctly in the comments after your question that the transpose is invertible.

In order to compute th matrix, we need a basis. I shall take the natural basis $\{E_{ij}\,|\,1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n\}$ where $E_{i,j}$ is the matrix $(a_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}$ with $a_{ij}=1$ and $a_{i'j'}=0$ if $(i',j')\neq(i,j)$. Let $T$ be the transpose. Then

- $(\forall i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):T(E_{ii})=E_{ii}$;
- $(\forall i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):i\neq j\implies T(E_{ij})=E_{ji}$.

Now, we must fix an order for the elements of the basis. I pick this order:

- first we have $E_{11},E_{22},\ldots,E_{nn}$;
- then we have the elements $E_{ij}$ with $i<j$ by some order;
- finally we have the remaing elements, inversing the order of the indexes from above; for instance, if the first elements of the previous type were $E_{12},E_{23},E_{13}$, now the first elements are $E_{21},E_{32},E_{31}$ and so on.

Then the matrix is something like$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}.$$(This is the case $n=4$.)

Comment: Sir , if you can explain it for the case n=2 . It will be easy for me to understand. I am asking about the transformation matrix of this transform which happens to be the Transpose.

Thanks

Comment: @AnshumanSinha In that case, the basis that I mentioned is $\{E_{11},E_{22},E_{12},E_{21}\}$. SInce $T(E_{11})=E_{11}$, $T(E_{22})=E_{22}$, $T(E_{12})=E_{21}$, and $T(E_{21})=E_{12}$, the matrix is$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$